# "print" menu not loading on Monoprice MP Select Mini V2

Tags: monoprice-select-mini, microsd

I have an MP Select Mini V2 and when I turn on the printer and select the "print" menu it hangs while saying "please wait" instead of listing the `.gcode` files stored on the SD card.

I have been using that printer with that SD card for hundreds of prints without error. It started when I took it out and added a new `.gcode` file (sliced in Cura with the same settings as I always use) and placed it back into the printer to print it. When I connect the SD card into my computer (Windows 10) everything seems normal with the card.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Please remove this file and see if standard behavior resumes. It's possible that the file name is too long, or has a special character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Too many files on SD card**

I removed some files and now it works, it seems like the menu would not load if the SD card contained more files than the printer could display on the print menu (they didn't take up a lot of space in memory, though).